# How to scale Seaborn's y-axis with a bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I'm using `factorplot(kind="bar")`.

How do I scale the y-axis, for example with log-scale?

I tried tinkering with the plots' axes, but that always messed up the bar plot in one way or another, so please try your solution first to make sure it really works.

Answer (score 56):

Considering your question mentions `barplot` I thought I would add in a solution for that type of plot also as it differs from the `factorplot` in @Jules solution.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

xs = ["First", "First", "Second", "Second", "Third", "Third"]
hue = ["Female", "Male"] * 3
ys = [1988, 301, 860, 77, 13, 1]

g = sns.barplot(x=xs, y=ys, hue=hue)
g.set_yscale("log")
_ = g.set(xlabel="Class", ylabel="Survived")
```

[image]

And if you want to label the y-axis with non-logarithmic labels you can do the following.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

xs = ["First", "First", "Second", "Second", "Third", "Third"]
hue = ["Female", "Male"] * 3
ys = [1988, 301, 860, 77, 13, 1]

g = sns.barplot(x=xs, y=ys, hue=hue)
g.set_yscale("log")

# the non-logarithmic labels you want
ticks = [1, 10, 100, 1000]
g.set_yticks(ticks)
g.set_yticklabels(ticks)

_ = g.set(xlabel="Class", ylabel="Survived")
```

[image]

Answer (score 27):

Note: `seaborn.factorplot` was replaced by [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html), which is a [figure-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) function.

`sns.catplot`, with `kind='bar'`, accepts the `log` parameter directly.

**Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

g = sns.catplot(x="class", y="survived", hue="sex",
                   data=titanic, kind="bar",
                   height=5, palette="muted", legend=False, log=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

You can use Matplotlib commands after calling `factorplot`.
For example:

```
g = sns.factorplot(x="class", y="survived", hue="sex",
                   data=titanic, kind="bar",
                   height=5, palette="muted", legend=False)
g.fig.get_axes()[0].set_yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you are facing the problem of vanishing bars upon setting log-scale using the previous solutions, try adding `log=True` to the seaborn function call instead.

**Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

Using [`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

g = sns.barplot(x="class", y="survived", hue="sex",
                data=titanic, palette="muted", log=True)
g.set_ylim(0.05, 1)
```

[image]

---

`sns.factorplot` is no longer part of `seaborn`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27107856/7758804) for the replacement.

Using `sns.factorplot`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

g = sns.factorplot(x="class", y="survived", hue="sex", kind='bar',
                   data=titanic, palette="muted", log=True)
g.ax.set_ylim(0.05, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Seaborn's [catplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) does not have anymore the `log` parameter.

For those looking for an **updated answer**, here's the quickest fix I've used: you have to use matplotlib's built-in support by accessing the axes object.

```py
g = sns.catplot(data=df, <YOUR PARAMETERS>)
for ax in g.fig.axes:
    ax.set_yscale('log')
```

Comment: This works, but the statement is wrong, and should be deleted. `log` is an accepted parameter, as tested in `seaborn v0.12.2`: [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPJgG.png) and shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27107856/7758804).