# How to plot a histogram using a logarithmic scale with Seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, histogram, seaborn

My question is fairly simple: I would like to visualize multiple histograms using the Seaborn module, however, as a number of bins contain very few counts, I would like to visualize the vertical axis using a logarithmic scale.

My code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,2), columns=['A','B'])
df = pd.melt(df, var_name='Category')     
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='Category', sharex=True, sharey=False, aspect=1.5)
g = g.map(plt.hist, "value", color="r")
```

, which gives me the following image: 
[image]

How do I change the vertical axis to a logarithmic scale (in the most 'pythonic'/'seabornic' way)? I've looked around on various answers, but wasn't satisfied with the answers I found so far.

**Update:**
Adding the following code, following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27019153/how-to-scale-seaborns-y-axis-with-a-bar-plot), makes my bars vanish:

```
g.fig.get_axes()[0].set_yscale('log')
```

**Update II:** 
The following code fixed my problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,2), columns=['A','B'])
df = pd.melt(df, var_name='Category')     
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='Category', sharex=True, sharey=False, aspect=1.5)
g = g.map(plt.hist, "value", color="r", log=True)
```

Answer (score 6):

I just added the last couple of lines:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,2), columns=['A','B'])
df = pd.melt(df, var_name='Category')  

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='Category', col_wrap=2, sharex=True, sharey=False, aspect=1.5)
g = g.map(plt.hist, "value", color="r")
g.axes[0].set_yscale('log')
g.axes[1].set_yscale('log')
```

[image]

Comment: The axes change to a logarithmic scale, but the bars dissappear. Any idea what the reason might be?