# How to plot a dodged barplot with dual axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I need to plot two sets of barplots side by side with their values on two separate y-axis.

In the example code below, my population bar is in different scale with income. It's not working with just one axis.

Here is what I need:

1. I need plot three bars for income of each region. Also I need three population bars right next to each of the income bar.
2. Because they are in different scale, I will need dual y axis.
3. Values on top of each bar.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = pd.DataFrame({'region': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
        'population': [1000, 2000, 30000],
        'income': [40, 50, 60]})
data = pd.melt(data, id_vars=['region'], var_name='metric', value_name='value')

sns.barplot(data=data, x='region', y= 'value', hue='metric')
```

Comment: Perhaps see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27019153/how-to-scale-seaborns-y-axis-with-a-bar-plot) which might be helpful.

Comment: how do I put values on top of those bars?

Comment: In terms of data presentation, this `data.plot(kind='bar', x='region', secondary_y='income', rot=0)` is not a good plot because, while there are two axes, visually having bars that are 60 and 30000 be the same length is misleading. Additionally, I don't see a way to extract the right `axes` in order to add a bar label. The better option is to use `log` scale on the y-axis. With the melted `data`: `ax = sns.barplot(data=data, x='region', y= 'value', hue='metric', log=True)` or with the first data: `ax = data.plot(kind='bar', x='region', rot=0, logy=True)`.

Comment: For either option, use `for c in ax.containers: ax.bar_label(c, label_type='edge')` to add labels.

Comment: See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fckWv.png)